# Qradar Error "An unexpected API error occurred. Please refer to the QRadar error logs for more information."

Tags: qradar

When installing some updates in Qradar, this error occurs

We have already solved the problem, I created a post just so that somewhere there is an answer to this error

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the Qradar locale language to en_us and the problem will go away.
We have not figured out how this is connected, but this solves the problem